# How to represent posts and likes in a REST API?

Tags: rest, api-design

Assume that in my REST API I have an endpoint for retrieving a post's data (`/posts/{id}`) and that in the response I include a property specific to the currently authenticated user, e.g. `isLiked`, so that the frontend can display the post differently (for example with a heart icon attached somewhere). Now, how should I organize my API to allow users to like each other's posts?

Currently I'm considering the following options:

- `POST /likes` with the body containing `"postId": ...`
- `POST /posts/{id}/likes`
- `PATCH /posts/{id}` with the body containing `"isLiked": true`

Note that I don't plan to add the possibility to get, list or delete likes.